# Ideas to create a unique identifier in firemonkey

Tags: firemonkey

I have been creating unique ids in my windows app and now that we are moving partly to mobile I am looking for a way to generate a unique id to be used as a primary key value in database work.

Does anyone have a way to do this in FireMonkey that they could share?

Thanks

John

Comment: Check out: `System.SysUtils.CreateGUID`.

Comment: Please add the language tag as applies (`delphi`, `c++builder`) and the version specific tag for the version you are using. It is also good to indicate in the question what the target platform is.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use GUID like Tom say :

```
uses
  SysUtils;

class function TPrimaryKey.GetKey: string;
begin
  // remove { } 
  // ex: 5b477ddd-0178-43a4-815a-08b3e81ef68e
  Result := TGUID.NewGuid.ToString().Replace('{', '').Replace('}', '');
end;
```